# How can I call a view that is in main activity from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a fragment that has a main activity with several views. One of them is a loading that I wanted to recycle between fragments. Is there a way to call a view in a fragment from main activity using kotlin?

Comment: Hi @Jose, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: please make your question clearer. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment, use `activity!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.your_view_id)` or better still,simply use `activity!!.your_view_id` then you can call any operation on the view.

**Note:**  replace *View* with your type of view e.g *TextView*